# I allways get the Error that the Not initialised variable hdc get used

Tags: c, windows

i´m trying to programm a traffic light, but i allways get the error 4700, idk what to do with HDC hdc;

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

[...]
```

the traffic light should run 4 times and than stop working. so i put the colors which should be changed in a for loop

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
```

HERE IS HDC hdc, i tried to google it but didnt get really an answer which would help me out to fix it

```
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HBRUSH gruen, gelb, rot, weiss;
    int i;
    

    //Punkte
    POINT PointsAmpel[4] = {50, 50, 250, 50, 250, 550, 50, 550};
```

Colors

```
    gelb = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 0));
    rot = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0));
    gruen = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 100, 0));
    weiss = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));

    switch (message)
    {

    case WM_PAINT:
        

       //Form

        Polygon(hdc, PointsAmpel, 4);

        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {   

            //rot ON
            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            Sleep(1000);
            SelectObject(hdc, rot);
            Ellipse(hdc, 100, 100, 200, 200);
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);               

            //+gelb ON
            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            Sleep(1000);
            SelectObject(hdc, gelb);
            Ellipse(hdc, 100, 250, 200, 350);
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);

            //rot+gelb OFF grün ON
            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            Sleep(1000);
            SelectObject(hdc, weiss);
            Ellipse(hdc, 100, 250, 200, 350);
            Ellipse(hdc, 100, 100, 200, 200);
            SelectObject(hdc, gruen);
            Ellipse(hdc, 100, 400, 200, 500);
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);               

            //grün OFF gelb ON
            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            Sleep(1000);
            SelectObject(hdc, weiss);
            Ellipse(hdc, 100, 400, 200, 500);
            SelectObject(hdc, gelb);
            Ellipse(hdc, 100, 250, 200, 350);
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);

            //gelb OFF rot ON
            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            Sleep(1000);
            SelectObject(hdc, weiss);
            Ellipse(hdc, 100, 250, 200, 350);
            SelectObject(hdc, rot);
            Ellipse(hdc, 100, 100, 200, 200);
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);

            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        return 0;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        DeleteObject(rot);
        DeleteObject(gelb);
        DeleteObject(gruen);
        DeleteObject(weiss);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: IIRC, you must extract the dc value from the WM_PAINT message parameters.

Comment: its inside the [...]

Comment: First, that isn't how you use `BeginPaint` and `EndPaint`. Both should be invoked at-most-*once* per `WM_PAINT` message. Second, what value do you think is in `hdc` at the time `Polygon(hdc, PointsAmpel, 4);` is invoked, and where do you think that value came from ?? Unrelated, sleeping in a WM_PAINT message is *not* a solution to anything, no matter what the problem may be.